# java.awt.Color en Java

Tags: java, color

Tengo un `jTextField` que quiero que esté bloqueado y veo que el color `GRAY` de la clase `Color de Java` es demasiado intenso, quisiera personalizarlo en un `RGB #C8C7C6` para verlo más claro.

¿Se puede agregar el # al color?

Código:

```
textField.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: [Mira](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color(int,%20int,%20int)) , rgb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí se puede agregar el `#` para obtener el color personalizado que buscas;
`Color` trae el metodo [`decode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Color.html#decode(java.lang.String)) el cual permite:

`textField.setBackground(Color.decode("#C8C7C6"));`

o también de la forma:

`textField.setBackground(Color.decode("0xC8C7C6"));`